# Outlook search highlights found keywords but doesn't hide irrelevant emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, search, google-workspace

Strange issue with Outlook 2010 search functionality running with GSuite App Sync for Outlook:
When searching for emails(with or without from/subject/etc keywords) with the search bar at the top right Outlook will highlight the matching keywords but it won't hide the rest of the emails. So I have to scroll through all the emails and looks for the yellow highlighter for emails that match the search term(s).

I've tried to reset the current view from View tab and also rebuild the Index but everything looks good on the surface.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Seems like a tough one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a recent Windows Update is causing this.
Have to wait for Microsoft to come up with a fix.
Meanwhile, a workaround is to remove Outlook from indexing or use web-based Outlook interface.

Comment: do you know which windows update caused that issue? this is driving me crazy and I would like to uninstall this patch